# Proving left adjoints are unique up to isomorphism (by using comma categories)

Tags: category-theory

*Edited to make it clearer in fairness to PTJ what was in my rather telegraphic notes, and what was my own garble!*

Looking at some old notes I took when sitting in on Peter Johnstone's famed category theory course, I found I had written down something like this as (one!) proof that if $F \dashv G$ and $F' \dashv G$ then $ F\cong F'$.

> Suppose we have both $F \dashv G \colon \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$
> with unit $\eta$ and $F' \dashv G \colon \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$
> with unit $\eta'$. Then for any $\mathsf{C}$-object $A$, by a familiar result, both $(FA, \eta_A)$ and
> $(F'A, \eta'_A)$ are initial objects of $(A \downarrow G)$. So, as initial objects, there must be an
> isomorphism $\alpha_A$ between them, which by the definition of arrows
> between $(A \downarrow G)$ objects means we have an isomorphism
> $\alpha_A \colon FA \to F'A.$ And these isomorphisms $\alpha_A$, $\alpha_{A'}$ assemble into a natural isomorphism $\alpha \colon F \to F'$, so we are done.
>
> To show that we do get a natural isomorphism, consider this square, for
> any $c\colon A \to A'$: \begin{array}{ccc} FA & \xrightarrow{Fc} &
> FA'\\[8pt] \downarrow{\alpha_A}&& \downarrow{\alpha_{A'}}\\[8pt] F'A
> &\xrightarrow{F'c }& F'\!A' \end{array} The two arrows along each route
> compose to give us an arrow  $FA \to F'\!A'$, so must be
> equal, as needed ...

And this is where my garble came! The thought should be not just that these are equal $\mathsf{D}$ arrows, but that they are equal as $(A \downarrow G)$ arrows, in fact $(A \downarrow G)$ arrows from $(FA, \eta_A)$ to $(F'A', \eta'_{A'}\circ c)$ -- as the excerpt from Izaak's notes in his comments makes clear was PTJ's claim (my own notes at this point had a distracting error).

Those two $\mathsf{D}$ arrows are indeed each $(A \downarrow G)$ arrows by the checks given by FShrike, and then are equal because $(FA, \eta_A)$ is initial.

I'll leave this in place in case Izaak's comment and FShrike's answer will be useful to someone else!!

Comment: I took this course last year. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgqjT.png) is the proof he gave then, which has slightly different notation but indeed eventually the point is that the arrows along each route give a morphism in the comma category (which isn't too hard to check).

Comment: Thanks Izaak -- looking back at my original notes, I'm sure this would have been what PTJ said back in the day, and which I at a crucial point misrecorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented argument is a little sloppy (I wouldn't be surprised if the errors / omissions are Johnstone's and not yours in the recording); "$f$" is an unintroduced symbol and really "$c$" should be "$f$" (or "$f$" should be "$c$") and you're right that the uniqueness doesn't quite mean what we want it to mean. But it's ok because the $G$-images do commute in this instance (this is also not the only way to prove uniqueness of adjoints).

So let's correct/continue and parse the presented proof. There is a unique isomorphism $\alpha_A:FA\cong F'A$ which satisfies $G(\alpha_A)\eta_A=\eta'_A$, for any object $A$. Fix now an arrow $f:A\to A'$ of arbitrary objects. There is some composite $k=G(\alpha_{A'})\eta_{A'}\circ f=\eta'_{A'}\circ f:A\to GF'A'$; there is a unique arrow $g:FA\to F'A'$ such that $G(g)\circ\eta_A=k$. We would like to show that both $g_1:=\alpha_{A'}\circ F(\color{red}{f})$ and $g_2:=F'(f)\circ\alpha_A$ foot the bill, as then $g_1=g_2$ and $\alpha_\bullet$ would assemble to a natural isomorphism $F\cong F'$ which also happens to be unique in that it plays nice with the adjunction units.

Alright, well: $$G(g_1)\circ\eta_A=G(\alpha_{A'})\circ GF(f)\circ\eta_A=G(\alpha_{A'})\circ\eta_{A'}\circ f=k$$And: $$G(g_2)\circ\eta_A=GF'(f)\circ G(\alpha_A)\circ\eta_A=GF'(f)\circ\eta'_{A}=\eta'_{A'}\circ f=k$$As desired.

Comment: Thanks for this (and apologies for the extra $f/c$ garble in my unedited qn.). Yes, the two displayed equations must have been exactly what PTJ wanted his audience to fill in!